# out of memory exception while using multithread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory

I am new to threading and stuck here on this issue. I have an application where I am using multi threading. I have a function which uploads thousands of images on ftp server. For each images I am creating a new thread. This thread calls a function to connect ftp server, upload file and returns boolean value if its successfully uploaded.

My problem is, since I am uploading thousands of images and each is creating its own thread, after sometime I get Out of Memory exception and application freezes.

My codes is as follows:

```
public Int16 UploadFiles(string[] files)
{
     foreach (var fileName in files)
        {
            if (UploadFile(fileName))
            {
                strLogText += "\r\n\tFile: " + fileName + " downloaded.";
            }
        }
}

private bool UploadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var blnDownload = false;
        var thread = new Thread(() => DownLoadFileNow(fileName, out blnDownload)) {IsBackground = true};
        thread.Start();
        return blnDownload;
    }

    private void DownLoadFileNow(string fileName, out bool blnDownload)
    {
        //Get file path and name on source ftp server
        var srcFolder = GetSrcFolderName(fileName);

        //Get Local Folder Name for downloaded files
        var trgFolder = GetLocalFolder(fileName, "D");

        var reqFtp =
            (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + _strSourceFtpurl + srcFolder + "/" + fileName));
        reqFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFtp.UseBinary = true;
        reqFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_strSourceFtpUser, _strSourceFtpPassword);
        var outputStream = new FileStream(trgFolder + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        try
        {
            var response = (FtpWebResponse) reqFtp.GetResponse();
            var ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            const int bufferSize = 2048;
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            if (ftpStream != null)
            {
                int readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                ftpStream.Close();
            }
            response.Close();
            blnDownload = true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLog("Error in Downloading File (" + fileName + "):\r\n\t" + ex.Message, "");
            //Delete newly created file from local system
            outputStream.Close();
            if (File.Exists(trgFolder + "/" + fileName))
                File.Delete(trgFolder + "/" + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLog("Error in Downloading File (" + fileName + "):\r\n\t" + ex.Message, "");
        }
        finally
        {
            outputStream.Close();
            outputStream.Dispose();
        }
        blnDownload = false;
    }
```

Please help and let me know how I can limit the number of threads being created so that at a time, there are not more than 10-20 threads running.

Comment: [a thread uses 1MB of memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx); that's why you get the error. You need to use TPL instead, as suggested in the answers below.

Comment: Make a kind of queue, that limits how many things you can download at a time. Maybe try using Tasks instead of threads so you can know when they finish

Comment: Any Windows process that uses more than (8 * logical_processors) of threads will fail to perform or scale. For example, a single CPU system with an service application that uses more than 8 thread to process requests (e.g. socket accepts), will quickly take the box to its knees.

Comment: @DanielBullington - what?  I'm posting this from Firefox - 57 threads.  My i7 has 4/8 cores.  Kaspersky AV has 92 threads.  NT kernel and System has 257 threads.  Where did you get that 'more than (8 * logical_processors)' fallacy from?

Comment: The OP's problem is continually creating/terminating/destroying threads instead of submitting tasks to a threadpool.  For networked tasks that are mostly blocked on I/O, 64 threads in the pool is not unreasonable.

Comment: 64 threads in the pool is VERY unreasonable... thus the whole reason I/O completion ports exist in Windows for scalable networked servers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create this many threads. One alternative would be to use parrelle extensions.

```
public void UploadFiles(string[] files)
{
    files.AsParallel().ForAll(fileName =>
    {
        if (UploadFile(fileName))
        {
            strLogText += "\r\n\tFile: " + fileName + " downloaded.";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the foreach in UploadFiles(string[] files) with a Parallel.ForEach() that calls DownloadFileNow instead of the UploadFile(String file) method.

Parallel.Foreach will pull threads from a thread pool, which is what you want, and will simplify your code.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(files, fileName =>
        DownloadFileNow(fileName);
        strLogText += "\r\n\tFile: " + fileName + " downloaded.";
 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting "AggregateException was unhandled". any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I bet it has to do with updating the strLogText in an asynchronous manner. What do you do with strLogText?

Comment: I use to add in the log file at the end of the function to know how many files and which files are uploaded. instead of adding each time, I add them in string and after each loop ends, I add in log file.

Comment: I commented that line for strLogText, still I can see the same error.

Comment: Did it give you a line number in the AggregateException stack trace?

Comment: Parallel.ForEach(files, fileName =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bool blnDownload;
                        DownLoadFileNow(fileName, out blnDownload);
                        if (!blnDownload) return;
                        flCount++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _log.WriteLog(e.Message, "");////HERE it shows
                    }
                });

Comment: Try commenting out all of the logging you're doing in the Parallel.ForEach and the methods it calls. If that fixes the issue then the EventLogger you're using can't handle being called across multiple threads, in which case you could use a ConcurrentQueue or something similar to store your error messages and then log them when you've finished running, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx . If that's not the issue, then I would remove your catch(Exception) statement in the hopes of getting a better exception.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you shouldn't be creating that many threads. Now... The `Parallel.ForEach()` will give you nice syntactic sugar and you should go that route!

Just wanted to point out, that you need to look up thread pools as a concept. See, it doesn't make sense to have tons of threads running around in parallel. For each such task, there is an optimum number of threads, above which, the whole threading overhead will actually start to slow you down. Or, in your case, use up all your memory.

If you think about the task as a pile of photos sitting on a desk (the folder) and the threads as employees running errands for you, then having one employee fetch a photo from the desk, put it in an envelope and bring it to the post office, for each photo, is going to take forever. So you hire another employee. And another. But, once you reach a certain amount of photo-stamp-post-guys, they start to get in each others way. They queue up in front of the desk. They queue up in front of the post office. And the whole envelope situation is just painful for poor Mary in charge of office supplies - they're queuing up in front of her too! So, figure out the optimal amount of employees (you could run tests or just guess a bit) and assign them to repeat that task until the desk is empty...

This is a master / slave pattern that shows up quite often.